# c# How to undo Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes or convert to File.ReadAllBytes

Tags: c#, binary, streamreader

C# application was written, to transfer files to FTP server. And function below was used to read jpeg file. This is bad function because it corrupts jpeg :

```
StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("image.jpeg");
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

The code below would work for the file transfer.:

```
 fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
```

And now i have library of corrupted jpegs.

How to fix the mess?

Comment: restore from backups.

Comment: @DanielA.White not an option. The files are from medical instrument data stream.Cannot be reproduced, only if experiment is repeated. And i can't be.

Comment: How do you suppose a read-only operation corrupted the file? That makes no sense to me. The destination files might not be good, but the source files should be just fine. As an aside, why are you even trying to open the stream yourself? Just use `File.ReadAllBytes("image.jpeg");`

Comment: The medical device has very low memory, and can only make couple of shots at a time, and then overrides it with new files. I - genius, decided to upload files to FTP is a good idea. And it was, only problem, that it is corrupted. And source files overwritten anyway. So no way to get source images. Only last 5 or so.

Comment: You can't read arbitrary bytes as UTF-8; UTF-8 bytes have to follow specific rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `StreamReader` at all for reading binary files, it's a `TextReader`. Even your 2nd piece of code is wrong, unless `sourceStream` only contains a file name.

It's likely that your data is corrupted beyond repair. You can do the inverse with `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and `StreamWriter`, but your encoding has most likely caused irreparable damage already.